# Creating a pair of virtual serial ports within a Docker container

Tags: powershell, docker, serial-port, com0com, com-port

I'm currently trying to create and connect a pair of virtual serial ports in a Docker container. It is imperative to link COM3 with and COM4 within the same container. It also has to be a Windows container.

I've tried com0com through the "install" command but the following message pops out and the ports are not successfully installed:

```
   DIALOG: {
UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices("root\com0com", "C:\Program Files (x86)\com0com\com0com.inf", 0x0)
ERROR: 13 - The data is invalid.
}
```

This works perfectly fine outside the Docker container (tested through PowerShell).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Containers don't have any sort of virtualized hardware.  You need a full virtual machine if you need to simulate serial ports or other devices.